# Find the domain of the function $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to solve the next problem: Given the function defined by $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}$$

then

1) find the domain of $f$

2) find the largest set where $f$ is continous

3) find the largest set where $f$ is differentiable

I tried to use the integral convergence test with no results, so it would be great that you provide me with some hints. Thanks

Comment: Are the terms decreasing or increasing ?

Comment: $x\geq 0$ is needed to have the general term bounded. That gives the domain and the largest set where $f$ is continuous. Then you may check that $f(x)$ is not differentiable in the origin but it is for any $x>0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Using $t=e^{-x}\ge 0$, we see that this series is a usual power series in $t$ where all the common techniques apply.